# Continuity of homomorphism with filter

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to prove one theorem in Enns page 43 (https://mspace.lib.umanitoba.ca/bitstream/handle/1993/21613/Enns_Pure_embeddings.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y): Let $(M,\tau)$ be a topological module. Let $D$ be a dense submodule of $M$, and let $L$ be a complete module. Every continuous homomorphism $f\colon D\to L$ extends uniquely to a continuous homomorphism $\overline{f}\colon M\to L$. That is, $\overline{f}i=f$, where $i\colon D\to M$.

### [image]

Proof:

1. Construction of $\overline{f}$: Let $m\in M$. Since $D$ is dense in $M$, there is a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $M$ such that $\mathcal{F}\xrightarrow{\tau} m$ and $D\in\mathcal{F}$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a Cauchy filter on $M$ so is its restriction $\mathcal{F}_{D}=\{F\subseteq D\mid F\in \mathcal{F}\}$. Furthermore, $f$ is continuous homomorphism, then $f(\mathcal{F}_{D})$ is a Cauchy filter on $L$. Since $L$ is complete, then $\lim f(\mathcal{F}_{D})$ exists. We define $\overline{f}(m)=\lim f(\mathcal{F}_{D})$ for every $m\in M$. $\overline{f}$ is well-defined, and $\overline{f}$ is unique because every filter on Hausdorff space is unique.
2. Next is to prove that $\overline{f}\colon M\to L$ is continuous. Let $N\subseteq L$ be an open subset of $L$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(N)$ is open subset in $D$. Hence, $f^{-1}(N)=D\cap K$, with $K$ is open subset in $M$, and $i(f^{-1}(N))=i(D\cap K)=D\cap K$, but $i$ is not an open map. Let $x\in D\cap K$, we have to find a neighborhood $U_{x}$ of $x$ such that $x\in U_{x}\subseteq D\cap K$. Since $\overline{D}=M$, then $x\in D\cap K\subseteq \overline{D}\cap K=M\cap K$. If I choose $U_{x}=M\cap K$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, but $M\cap K\subsetneq D\cap K$. Please help me to find $U_{x}$ such that $D\cap K$ is an open subset in $M$.
3. The last is to prove that $\overline{f}$ is a homomorphism, i.e., $\overline{f}(m_{1}+m_{2})=\overline{f}(m_{1})+\overline{f}(m_{2})$ for every $m_{1},m_{2}\in M$. From construction of $\overline{f}$, if $m_{1},m_{2},m_{1}+m_{2}\in M$, we can construct filter $\mathcal{F}_{1}$, $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, and $\mathcal{F}$ on $M$ such that $\mathcal{F}_{1}\xrightarrow{\tau} m_{1}$, $\mathcal{F}_{2}\xrightarrow{\tau} m_{2}$, $\mathcal{F}\xrightarrow{\tau} m_{1}+m_{2}$ and $D\in\mathcal{F}_{1},\mathcal{F}_{2},\mathcal{F}$.  Furthermore, we can construct filter $\mathcal{F}_{1D}=\{F\subseteq D\mid F\in \mathcal{F}_{1}\}$, $\mathcal{F}_{2D}=\{F\subseteq D\mid F\in \mathcal{F}_{2}\}$, and $\mathcal{F}_{D}=\{F\subseteq D\mid F\in \mathcal{F}\}$ which are Cauchy filter since $\mathcal{F}_{1}$, $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, and $\mathcal{F}$ are Cauchy filter on $M$. Hence $f(\mathcal{F}_{1D})$, $f(\mathcal{F}_{2D})$, and $f(\mathcal{F}_{D})$ are Cauchy filter on $L$. We have $L$ is a complete module, then $f(\mathcal{F}_{1D})$, $f(\mathcal{F}_{2D})$, and $f(\mathcal{F}_{D})$ are convergent, so $\lim f(\mathcal{F}_{1D})$, $\lim f(\mathcal{F}_{2D})$, and $\lim f(\mathcal{F}_{D})$ exist. How to prove $\lim f(\mathcal{F}_{D})=\lim f(\mathcal{F}_{1D})+\lim f(\mathcal{F}_{2D})$? I know the union of two filters is not a filter. Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: If you work with nets instead of filters, calculations become much easier. Just don't forget to prove, that you always find a common index set, i.e. there is an upward directed $I$ such that for all $m \in M$ there is a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in $D$, which converges to $m$. But this is easy!

Comment: I will try your advice, thank you so much!